# How to read YoloV3/YoloV4 in OpenCv to get the detections?

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection

I have `OpenCv` version `cv2.__version__` = '4.0.1' and I'm trying to use Yolov3 and YoloV4 using OpenCv. I used weights and configs from the [AlexyAB's DarkNet git repo](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet)

[Yolov4.config](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/blob/master/cfg/yolov4.cfg)
[YoloV4.weights](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/releases/download/darknet_yolo_v3_optimal/yolov4.weights)

and same for the classes as [coco.names/ classes.txt](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/blob/master/cfg/coco.names)

I used many different modules but not able to open the model.

```
class DLFeaturesExtractor():
    '''
    Classs to Extract features from Image and plot on a Deep Learning Model
    '''
    def __init__(self,weight:str,config:str,cuda:bool=False,size:[tuple,list]=(416,416)):
        '''
        args:
            weight: path of weight file
            config: path to config file
            cuda: whether to use GPU and CudNN algos
            size: size of the input image
        '''
        self.weight = weight
        self.config = config
        net = cv2.dnn.readNet(self.weight,self.config)
        if cuda:
            net.setPreferableBackend(cv2.dnn.DNN_BACKEND_CUDA)
            net.setPreferableTarget(cv2.dnn.DNN_TARGET_CUDA_FP16)
        self.model = cv2.dnn_DetectionModel(net)
        self.model.setInputParams(size=size,scale=1/255)
```

Running the code gives me error as:

```
error: OpenCV(4.0.1) C:\ci\opencv-suite_1573470242804\work\modules\dnn\src\darknet\darknet_importer.cpp:207: error: (-212:Parsing error) Failed to parse NetParameter file: yolov4.cfg in function 'cv::dnn::dnn4_v20181221::readNetFromDarknet'
```

So I used different things as:

```
cv2.dnn.readNetFromDarknet('yolov4.cfg','yolov4.weights',)
```

gave me

```
error: OpenCV(4.0.1) C:\ci\opencv-suite_1573470242804\work\modules\dnn\src\darknet\darknet_io.cpp:552: error: (-212:Parsing error) Unsupported activation: mish in function 'cv::dnn::darknet::ReadDarknetFromCfgStream'
```

I thought there might be parameter interchange so I did it too and same error keeps coming.

Can someone please help how can I open and make inference from the model?

I used [this gist](https://gist.github.com/YashasSamaga/e2b19a6807a13046e399f4bc3cca3a49) to get the idea but nothing seems to work.

Comment: https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/wiki/YOLOv4-model-zoo

Take the model and the cfg from here and avoid the version with mish activation, that I think is not supported in the version of OpenCV that you're using.

Comment: Just used `opencv-contrib`. Worked for me. Thanks for the suggestion. Also, How can I throw an error as if `opencv-contrib` is not installed?

Answer (score 1):

Please note that Yolov4 is not supported by Opencv 4.2.0 and 4.3.0.
Try to download the last version in master branch support YoloV4 (according to [KyloEntro](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/17479))

Personally, I have upgraded opencv-python to version 4.5.3.56, and there is no more error!